# Creating Columns in a View That Use an Aggregate Method in a Case...When Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum, case-when

I am trying to create a view in SQL Server that renders columns from 3 tables and that creates 4 NEW columns.  These new columns use the SQL "Case...When" syntax to conditionally render the SUM of existing fields depending on the values of an adjacent column [Portfolio Report Category] in the same table.

The objective is to display a single account's total market value for 4 distinct asset categories.  Right now an [Account Number] can have MANY records with MANY [Investment Amount] for a single [Portfolio Report Category].  So obviously this view should allow an [Account Number] to have only ONE record with 4 summed monetary values that meet the "Case...When" conditions.

I have read similar threads, but none that addresses an aggregate method after the "Then" keyword in the conditional block.  When I place the Sum() before "Case" and remove it after the "Then,"  there is no error but the calculations are wrong:  In many cases, they are much higher.  I was under the impression that a simple Try_Convert to money would be sufficient, and indeed if I execute SUM(Try_Convert(money, [Market_Value]) Where [Account Number] = 'x', the result is correct.  But not when I'm creating the view.

Here is the error when testing the following code with SELECT:

> Column 'KTHoldings.Portfolio Report Category' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Further below is the KTHoldings table returning all records for a single account.  I basically need the [Other Total Value] column of my view to sum its [Market Value] data.

```
CREATE VIEW VW_KTAccountsADR AS (
    SELECT adr.[Account Number], adr.[Account_ Display Name], adr.[Account Category Code], adr.[Division Code], adr.[Division Name], adr.[Market Value Amount],
    CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] = '705' THEN SUM((TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value]))) ELSE '0.00' END AS [Crypto Total Value], 
    CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] = '691' THEN SUM((TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value]))) ELSE '0.00' END AS [Precious Metal Total Value],
    CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] IN ('010', '011', '020', '025', '030') THEN SUM((TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value]))) ELSE '0.00' END AS [Stock Total Value],
    CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] NOT IN ('010', '011', '020', '025', '030', '691', '705') THEN SUM((TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value]))) ELSE '0.00' END AS [Other Total Value],
    ktc.[Available Cash Amount] AS [CASH TOTAL]
    FROM KTAccountsADR adr
    INNER JOIN KTHoldings kth
    ON adr.[Account Number] = kth.[Account Number]
    INNER JOIN KTCash ktc 
    ON adr.[Account Number] = ktc.[Account Number]
    GROUP BY adr.[Account Number], adr.[Account_ Display Name], adr.[Account Category Code], adr.[Division Code], adr.[Division Code], adr.[Division Name], adr.[Market Value Amount], ktc.[Available Cash Amount]
)
```

**KTAccountsADR Table**

```
Account Number          Display Name      Division Code   Market Value Amount
07007835        Frank C Thomas Roth IRA           27             390410.98
07007835        Frank C Thomas Roth IRA           27             390410.98
07007835        Frank C Thomas Roth IRA           27             390410.98
07007835        Frank C Thomas Roth IRA           27             390410.98
001000          Carl S Sykes Roth IRA             27           196338.1292            
001000          Carl S Sykes Roth IRA             27           196338.1292
001000          Carl S Sykes Roth IRA             27           196338.1292
```

**KTHoldings Table**

```
Account Number  Display Name    Market Value    Portfolio Report Category
001000  Carl S Sykes Roth IRA   9998.4792        600
001000  Carl S Sykes Roth IRA   43467.09         600
001000  Carl S Sykes Roth IRA   84524.71         600
```

**KTCash Table**

```
Account Number  Available Cash Amount
001000               58347.85
```

Comment: FYI: Tables have columns, not fields.

Comment: Your logic is not clear, if the `sum` is to be conditional on the value of `kth.[Portfolio Report Category]` then you need to `group by kth.[Portfolio Report Category]` because otherwise, if `kth.[Portfolio Report Category]` can have a different value for each row, how would sum work?

Comment: Therein lies your problem, you have multiple, duplicate, rows in your `KTAccountsADR` table, so when you join your `KTHoldings` table on they multiple.

Comment: Your acumen is much appreciated.  I was not even paying attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `case` inside your `sum`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] = '705' THEN TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value]) ELSE '0.00' END) AS [Crypto Total Value],
```

Here is a working example:

```
declare @Adr table ([Account Number] varchar(6), [Account_ Display Name] varchar(64), [Account Category Code] varchar, [Division Code] varchar, [Division Name] varchar, [Market Value Amount] money);
declare @Kth table ([Account Number] varchar(6), [Portfolio Report Category] varchar(3), [Market Value] money);
declare @Ktc table ([Account Number] varchar(6), [Available Cash Amount] money);

insert into @Adr ([Account Number], [Account_ Display Name])
values ('001000', 'Carl S Sykes Roth IRA');

insert into @Kth ([Account Number], [Market Value], [Portfolio Report Category])
values ('001000', 9998.4792, '600'),
('001000', 43467.09, '600'),
('001000', 84524.71, '600');

insert into @Ktc ([Account Number])
values ('001000');

SELECT adr.[Account Number], adr.[Account_ Display Name], adr.[Account Category Code], adr.[Division Code], adr.[Division Name], adr.[Market Value Amount]
  , SUM(CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] = '705' THEN (TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value])) ELSE 0 END) AS [Crypto Total Value] 
  , SUM(CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] = '691' THEN (TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value])) ELSE 0 END) AS [Precious Metal Total Value]
  , SUM(CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] IN ('010', '011', '020', '025', '030') THEN (TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value])) ELSE 0 END) AS [Stock Total Value]
  , SUM(CASE WHEN kth.[Portfolio Report Category] NOT IN ('010', '011', '020', '025', '030', '691', '705') THEN (TRY_CONVERT(money, kth.[Market Value])) ELSE 0 END) AS [Other Total Value]
  , ktc.[Available Cash Amount] AS [CASH TOTAL]
FROM @Adr adr
INNER JOIN @Kth kth ON adr.[Account Number] = kth.[Account Number]
INNER JOIN @Ktc ktc  ON adr.[Account Number] = ktc.[Account Number]
GROUP BY adr.[Account Number], adr.[Account_ Display Name], adr.[Account Category Code], adr.[Division Code], adr.[Division Code], adr.[Division Name], adr.[Market Value Amount], ktc.[Available Cash Amount];
```

Which returns (un-necessary columns removed):

```
Account Number  Crypto Total Value  Precious Metal Total Value  Stock Total Value   Other Total Value   CASH TOTAL
001000          0.00                0.00                        0.00                137990.2792         NULL
```

Edit: As you have now added sample data, the reason you were getting incorrect values is because you had duplicate rows in your `KTAccountsADR` which then multiple the rows in the `KTHoldings` table. Resolve the duplicates and you will get the correct values when using `case` inside `sum`.

Note, its best practice to ensure you are returning the same datatype from all branches of a `case` expression.

Comment: @H.Olsen ok you need to add enough sample data and expected results to understand what you are asking - because the logic just doesn't work as it stands.

Comment: When I use the case inside your sum you state, the example account above (# 00100) returns $413,970.8376, when the obvious result needed is $137,990.2792.  So for instance, this account should return $0.00 for the other three new view columns, because his only kth.[Portfolio Report Category] fields are '600.'

Comment: @H.Olsen that sounds like you are getting duplicate rows due to your joins, if you try your query without the `group by` and without the sums I expect you will find more rows than you want.

Comment: You'll notice the amount you are getting is exactly 3 times the amount you want - which is a sure indication that there are duplicate rows.

Comment: The joins result in no duplicate adr.[Account Number] fields.  This is actually what I want.  Grouping by kth.[Portfolio Report Category] does result in duplicates, so it's not useful.

Comment: OK, well the only way we can help is if you post sample data from all the tables in question. I promise you the joins are duplicating rows - else how would the sum be 3 times larger than expected? Show us sample data for all 3 tables.

Comment: Alright, great.  I will edit the OP.  Btw I think you are right!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221598/discussion-between-h-olsen-and-dale-k).

Comment: @DaleK What is the benefit of having `ELSE '0.00'` rather than `ELSE 0` in a `sum`?

Comment: @HABO probably none... I just copied OPs code and rearranged it - I try not to overthink these things :)

Comment: @HABO It's preferable.  I have to bind to <asp:literal> [text] anyway.

Comment: @H.Olsen According to the rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when you muddle `money` with `varchar` the result will be `money`. (`select SQL_Variant_Property( case when 1 = 0 then Cast( -1 as Money ) else '42.00' end, 'basetype' );`)

Comment: @DaleK I will go ahead and ensure only money is returned in the branches.  Our SQLCommands were already doing this in C#, but with the view, I only need to run .ToString() before rendering (to <Asp:Literal>).